# How do I execute multiple PHP files in single shell line?

Tags: php, linux, shell, gnu-screen

I have some PHP files. Each of them start a socket listener, or run an infinite loop. The scripts halt when are executed via `php` command:

```
php sock_listener.php ...halt there
php listener2.php ... halt there
...
```

Currently I use `screen` command to start all the listener PHP files every time the machine is rebooted. Is there a way I can start all the listener PHP files in single shell line so that I can write a shell script to make it easier to use?

Comment: don't use `exec` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using screen

Create a detached screen session for the first script:

```
session='php-test'
screen -S "$session" -d -m -t A php a.php
```

where `-d -m` combination causes screen to create a detached session.

Run the rest of the scripts in the same session in separate windows:

```
screen -S "$session" -X screen -t B php b.php
screen -S "$session" -X screen -t C php c.php
```

where

- `-X` sends the *built-in* `screen` command to the running session;
- `-t` sets the window title.

The session will be available in the output of `screen -ls` command:

```
There is a screen on:
  8951.php-test (Detached)
```

Connect to the session using `-r` option, e.g.:

```
screen -r 8951.php-test
```

List the windows within the screen session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> shortcut, or `windowlist -b` command.

## Forking Processes to Background

A less convenient way is to send the commands to background by appending an ampersand at the end of each command:

```
nohup php a.php 2>a.php.err >a.php.out &
nohup php b.php 2>b.php.err >b.php.out &
nohup php c.php 2>c.php.err >c.php.out &
```

where

- `nohup` prevents termination of the commands, if the user logs out of the shell. Read [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) for more information;
- `2>a.php.err` redirects the standard error to `a.php.err` file;
- `>a.php.out` redirects the standard output to `a.php.out` file.

---

> Is there a way I can start all the listener PHP files in single shell line so that I can write a shell script to make it easier to use?

You can put the above-mentioned commands into a shell script file, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash -
# Put the commands here
```

make it executable:

```
chmod +x /path/to/script
```

and call it when you need it:

```
/path/to/script
```

Modify the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answers, question modification as well.

Comment: I put 2 screen commands into a shell script and call it, the second screen line is not reached because that it stucks at the first screen session, I have to press ctrl+a-d, then the second screen line is started. While I need a shell script which can open 2 screen sessions just by calling it, no need additional operations. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @MarcusM, the shell script should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/a0044b80f280b8cd3b6cde2632ed6f58) (_three_ `screen` commands). When you launch it: `./script.sh`, it doesn't forward you to the screen session, since it is detached.

Comment: Excuse me. The network cannot access github, my vpn proxy doesn't work today. Could you please paste the content of the this link page?

Comment: Cherring! It works.

The shell script finally looks like this:
`#!/usr/bin/bash`

`nohup php myfile1.php 2>path/myfile1.err >myfile1.out &`

`nohup php myfile2.php 2>path/myfile2.err >myfile2.out`
``
`echo "Startup done."`
`exit`

By the way, if the sh is edited in vi, I have to set ff=unix.

Besides that, I have no idea about the '&' symbol in the .sh. When should I attach it to the end of the line.

Anyway, Thank you very much @Ruslan Osmanov. You helped me a lot.

Comment: @MarcusM, the `&` symbol sends the preceding command to background so you can proceed without the need to wait until the command finishes. `nohup` makes sure that the command will continue running, if you log out . If you think that the answer solves the problem, consider accepting and/or upvoting it

Comment: Of course it do solve the problem. Stackoverflow is so good. Thanks a lot.
But Sorry...where is the accepting btn?

Comment: I've accepted your answer, right? Can I ask another question? You said the & symbol makes it proceed without waiting the command to finish. What makes me confused is that the `make install` is not proceed until `make` is finished when we type `make&make install` to install sth. I've always thought the & symbol just queue up several commands, while they are proceed one by one

Comment: @MarcusM, you are confusing single ampersand (`&`) with double ampersand (`&&`). The latter is a logical _AND_ operator that executes the right-hand command, if the left-hand command returns _true_ (i.e. terminates with exit status zero). Thus, `&&` works synchronously, and the right-hand command is executed only after the left-hand command is terminated (successfully).

Comment: Shamed. I was supposed to be more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Just run them under circus.  Circus will let you define a number of processes and how many instances you want to run, and just keep them running.
https://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/